# Car wont start with the radio on

Tags: starting, audio

Its just a minor issue that bugs me. My Ford Focus 2005 1.6 Petrol wont start if the radio is ON. Just cranks. The battery is like 4 weeks old. Brand new.
Its not a big deal but that never happened with my previous cars so I'm just concerned.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a new issue or has been doing it since you've owned it?

Comment: Well, I bought it from a guy a week ago, changed the radio fuse because it was blown.